# How to handle Includes with Entity Framework Core in Domain Driven Design

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I am fairly new with the concept of domain driven design and just need a nudge in the right direction. I couldn't find anything on the internet for my problem that I am satisfied with. I have an application I built following the domain driven design. Now I am wondering how I can implement includes without using EFC in my application layer. I have a presentational layer (Web API), an application layer that consists of commands and queries (I am using CQRS), a domain layer which stores my models and has the core business logic and my persistence layer that implements Entity Framework Core and a generic repository that looks like this:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity
    {
        private readonly HeimdallContext _context;

        public Repository(HeimdallContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IQueryable<T> Get()
        {
            return _context.Set<T>();
        }

        public async Task<T> FindAsync(Guid id)
        {
            return await _context.Set<T>().SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
        }

        public T Add(T item)
        {
            return _context.Add(item).Entity;
        }

        public T Delete(T item)
        {
            return _context.Remove(item).Entity;
        }

        public T Update(T item)
        {
            return _context.Update(item).Entity;
        }

        public async Task SaveChangesAsync()
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

A query looks like this:

```
 public class FindFlowQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<FindFlowQuery, Result<GetUserFlow>>
    {
        private readonly IRepository<UserFlow> _userFlowRepository;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public FindFlowQueryHandler(IRepository<UserFlow> userFlowRepository, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _userFlowRepository = userFlowRepository;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        public async Task<Result<GetUserFlow>> Handle(FindFlowQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var userFlow = await Task.FromResult(_userFlowRepository
                .Get()
                //.Include(x => x.UserFlowQuestionAnswers)
                //    .ThenInclude(x => x.FlowQuestion)
                //        .ThenInclude(x => x.Localization)
                //.Include(x => x.UserFlowQuestionAnswers)
                //    .ThenInclude(x => x.Image)
                .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == request.UserFlowId));

            if (userFlow == null)
            {
                return new Result<GetUserFlow>(new UserFlowNotFoundError(request.UserFlowId));
            }

            if (userFlow.UserId != request.UserId)
            {
                return new Result<GetUserFlow>(new ForbiddenError());
            }

            var mappedUserFlow = _mapper.Map<GetUserFlow>(userFlow);

            return new Result<GetUserFlow>(mappedUserFlow);
        }
    }
```

I commented out the lines that make use of the `Include` method from EFC. I don't want the application layer to know anything about EFC, it shouldn't matter what ORM I use. Maybe one day I don't even want to use an ERM anymore. I know that a generic repository could be considered an overgeneralisation but I really like the idea of it and I don't want to write hundreds of repositories so that I can have methods like "`GetFlowWithQuestionsAndAnswersAndLocalizationAndImages()`" and so on.

I considered using the query specification pattern ([described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/infrastructure-persistence-layer-implementation-entity-framework-core#implement-the-query-specification-pattern)) but this seems like an overcomplication and it looks very EFC-specific to me. Ideally I don't want to specify includes at all in my application layer. I have a model, I know that it has other models as properties and I want to be able to access them. It shouldn't matter where they come from and that EFC treats them as navigation properties.

What is the best practice here? Just deactivating EFC lazy loading? Scrapping the generic repository? Working on `Queryables` all the time?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned in the question, using *Generic Repository* is not recommended by most DDD practitioners, because you lose the *Meaningful Contract* aspect of *Repository* in DDD, but if you insist, you can enrich your *Generic Repository* to have necessary aspects of your ORM like `include` in *Entity Framework*.

Be careful of adding more functionalities in your *Generic Repository* because it gradually transforms to a DAO.

Your *Generic Repository* could be something like this:

```
public class Repository<TContext>
    where TContext : DbContext
{
    protected readonly TContext context;

    public Repository(TContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    protected virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetQueryable<TEntity>(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = null,
        int? skip = null,
        int? take = null)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        includeProperties ??= string.Empty;
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = context.Set<TEntity>();

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        query = includeProperties.Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Aggregate(query, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            query = orderBy(query);
        }

        if (skip.HasValue)
        {
            query = query.Skip(skip.Value);
        }

        if (take.HasValue)
        {
            query = query.Take(take.Value);
        }

        return query;
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll<TEntity>(
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = null,
        int? skip = null,
        int? take = null)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        return GetQueryable<TEntity>(null, orderBy, includeProperties, skip, take).ToList();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get<TEntity>(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = null,
        int? skip = null,
        int? take = null)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        return GetQueryable<TEntity>(filter, orderBy, includeProperties, skip, take).ToList();
    }
}
```

For more information about the implementation of this *Repository*, take a look at [A Truly Generic Repository](https://cpratt.co/truly-generic-repository/)

Comment: Thank you so much! Hypothetically if i would scrap my generic repository, would you recommend having a repository for each entity then? And would you recommend including every property every time or having different methods depending on what I need? And how deep should I go, more than 1 property? (ThenInclude) It's always a struggle between performance and clean code.

Comment: You're welcome, every aggregate-root should have a *Repository* and every *Repository* should have methods that your use-case needs. Don't worry about the clean code, if you follow the DDD principles, your code is always clean. Performance should be considered, but it should not violate the DDD principles, it is another level of developing a system and it is the architectural concern. GOOD LUCK